# How can I capture video using java?

Tags: java

I want to ask is it possible to capture a video using java programming? If it is then how to do it??? I searched a lot but not getting satisfatory answer..
Thank You
Actually I want to capture all current activities on desktop...Like video shoot....

Comment: Capture video from what? A stream, usb, firewire, screengrab??

Comment: i want to capture all the current activities of desktop like video shoot

Comment: So like in a screencast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Robot](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)) class.  And there is a blog post here that uses that Method.

http://javagraphics.blogspot.com/2008/06/screen-capture-recording-java-apps.html

Answer (score 2):

http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/

Answer (score 0):

Do it with [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler).  Here's the [exact code](http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction#How_To_Take_Snapshots_Of_Your_Desktop) you need.

Comment: I replaced line: ***writer.adaddVideoStream(0, 0, FRAME_RATE,screenBounds.width, screenBounds.height);*** with   ***writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, screenBounds.width, screenBounds.height);*** since I don't know which ID to use. This is not working for me, it only renders .mp4 file and the whole screen is black. Which ID should I use?